# Paypal method for instant pay with later on charge too and recurring payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

We have one application that sell online account as service and we have work flow as per blow requirement.

- With user registration charge $10 instant and set recurring from next month
- If user add addons then user will charged extra $1 instant and update recurring with $1 extra (so $11)
- Same as unlimited addons with extra charges.

What methods is perfect with Paypal. 
I know it's really easy with Authorized.Net CIM & Recurring method. I am looking for something similar in Paypal.

For many time instant charge I think I need to create customer account with store credit card in Paypal but I don't want to create customer's Paypal account. Might be that customer have already account than my application will give me error and also there are many other problems too like user can remove credit card any time from account that I don't want.

I show there are so many different methods available in Paypal but did not get it which one is perfect for requirement.

I want to do everything on my website and don't want to use any express checkout method on Paypal side and I am working with Asp.Net with C#.Net

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Recurring Payments API is what you want.  Specifically, Express Checkout would be for PayPal payments and Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment / PayFlow) would be for direct credit card processing without a PayPal account.

Comment: Can you give me link for recurring docs which I can integrate on my website side I don't want to redirect to to paypal.

Comment: @AjmeraInfo - [PayPal REST API Billing Plans and Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements) will allow you to setup recurring payments. There's also a [PayPal REST API SDK for .NET](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet) that provides quick access to the PayPal REST API; however the SDK does not yet support the recurring payments feature. That support will be coming very soon, though. :)